# Return From Seuquelize then block of code in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, orm, sequelize.js

Im trying to return an array of elements from the the then block of Sequelize but the output is unpredicted. Its [object Promise].

Here is the code im trying to run.

```
                const trips = ServiceProviderTrip.findAll({
                    where: { locationId: location, userId: UserID },
                })
                    .then((result2) => {
                        //TODO: to get the tripid of those locationid having same
                        const trips = [];
                        const json2 = result2;
                        for (var i = 0; i < json2.length; i++) {
                            var obj = json2[i];
                            var tripId = obj.tripID;
                            trips.push(tripId);
                        }
                        return trips
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.log(red.inverse.bold(error))
                    });
                console.log(chalk.yellow.inverse.bold(trips))
```

And the output is:

```
[object Promise]
```

But what i want is:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

Thankyou in advance for solving and helping me. Gods of JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `trips` variable is not waiting for result.

Your code is synchronous

```
const trips = ServiceProviderTrip.findAll({
    where: { locationId: location, userId: UserID },
}).then((result2) => {
    //TODO: to get the tripid of those locationid having same
    const trips = [];
    const json2 = result2;
    for (var i = 0; i < json2.length; i++) {
        var obj = json2[i];
        var tripId = obj.tripID;
        trips.push(tripId);
    }
    return trips
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(red.inverse.bold(error))
});
// If you want to get result here you have to write Asynchronous code 
console.log(chalk.yellow.inverse.bold(trips))
```

Write Asynchronous code like this :

```
const getTrips = async ()=>{
    const trips = await ServiceProviderTrip.findAll({
        where: { locationId: location, userId: UserID },
    }).then((result2) => {
        //TODO: to get the tripid of those locationid having same
        const trips = [];
        const json2 = result2;
        for (var i = 0; i < json2.length; i++) {
            var obj = json2[i];
            var tripId = obj.tripID;
            trips.push(tripId);
        }
        return trips
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(red.inverse.bold(error))
    });
    console.log(chalk.yellow.inverse.bold(trips))
}

getTrips()
```

Or you can get your `trips` value in `.then` -

```
ServiceProviderTrip.findAll({
    where: { locationId: location, userId: UserID },
}).then((result2) => {
    //TODO: to get the tripid of those locationid having same
    const trips = [];
    const json2 = result2;
    for (var i = 0; i < json2.length; i++) {
        var obj = json2[i];
        var tripId = obj.tripID;
        trips.push(tripId);
    }
    console.log(chalk.yellow.inverse.bold(trips))
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(red.inverse.bold(error))
});
```

Comment: Absolute Genius Sir.